# Collecting company data from accident reports

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv

```
name = company_location
for i, j in enumerate (list):
    if j == 'Last 10 Accidents':
        last = i
        try:
            date1 = list[last+28]
            employee1 = list[last+31]
            days_lost1 = list[last+49]
            days_paid1 = list[last+43]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(str(name)+", "+str(date1)+", "+str(employee1)+", "+str(days_lost1)+", "+str(days_paid1))
            report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(str(name)+"\n")
            report.close()

        try:
            date2 = list[last+50]
            employee2 = list[last+53]
            days_lost2 = list[last+71]
            days_paid2 = list[last+65]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(", "+str(date2)+", "+str(employee2)+",     "+str(days_lost2)+", "+str(days_paid2))
            report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write("\n")
            report.close()

        try:
            date3 = list[last+72]
            employee3 = list[last+75]
            days_lost3 = list[last+93]
            days_paid3 = list[last+87]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(", "+str(date3)+", "+str(employee3)+", "+str(days_lost3)+", "+str(days_paid3))
            report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write("\n")
            report.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for i, j in enumerate (list):
> ```

You can't iterate through `list` because it is a type, so I am assuming that `list` is the name of a variable that you defined earlier on.  Don't do that.  When you use the name of something built-in for something else, you are overriding the variable that was previously defined.  If, for instance, you wanted to iterate through a list of tuples, but you actually wanted a list of lists, you could do `for sub in map(list, tuples):`, but with `list` redefined, you can't do that.  Besides that, it may confuse future readers of your code to be using `list` there when you can't iterate through a type.  Instead, use a name that not only says what type of object it is, but describes what is inside.

You have quite a bit of duplicate code in that `if j == 'Last 10 accidents':` block.  You should instead use a `for` loop iterating through different starting points.  That is, `for start in (28, 50, 72):` and use `date = list[last + start]`, `employee = date[list + start + 3]`, ...  You should be using a more descriptive name than `list` anyway, but I outlined that above.

> ```
> with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
>     report.write(str(name)+", "+str(date1)+", "+str(employee1)+", "+str(days_lost1)+", "+str(days_paid1))
> ```

Using a long string (no pun intended) of concatenations doesn't seem very good, does it?  Instead, use `.join()`:

```
info = (name, date1, employee1, days_lost1)
report.write(", ".join(map(str, info)) + "\n")
```

That shortens the code and makes it a little easier to see what you are doing.

> ```
> report.close()
> ```

The `with` statement will take care of closing the file so you don't need that line.

Your modified program would look like this:

```
name = company_location
for i, j in enumerate(reports):
    if j == 'Last 10 Accidents':
        last = i 
        for start in (28, 50, 72):
            try:
                date = reports[last + start]
                employee = reports[last + start + 3]
                days_lost = reports[last + start + 21] 
                days_paid = reports[last + start + 15] 
                info = (date, employee, days_lost, days_paid)
                with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                    report.write(", ".join(map(str, info)) + "\n")
            except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
                with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                    report.write(str(name)+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, zondo.  That is exactly what I needed.  I appreciate you helping me get over my hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to :

- add another `for` loop over `k`, before the `try` statements which would become unique,
- replace the variables such as `datek` by arrays, like `date[k]`,
- and the variables such as `list[last+28]` by `k` dependent ones, like `list[last+16+k]`.